# ¿Cómo validar un formulario con jQuery al enviarlo?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web, aplicación-web

Estoy desarrollando para un proyecto final la web de un taller mecánico.
Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un div vacío donde recargo por Jquery Ajax un php con un formulario cuando el usuario le da al botón "registrar vehículo".

El problema es que quiero hacer un control de errores tipo, "el vehículo ya existe en la base de datos", "vehículo introducido correctamente", pero al enviar el formulario, el jquery me desaparece..

La única solución que se me ocurre es que después de enviar el formulario, vuelva a meter en el div con jQuery ajax el mismo php, y en un span le metemos el error, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo.. si alguien tiene una posible solución, u otra manera de hacerlo lo agradezco.

Un saludo.

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.registrar').click(function () {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
        $('.eliminar').css("display", "inline");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registrarVehiculo.php",
            success: function (data) {
                $('.recargar').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
"<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
        <link href='estilos/estilosUser.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
        
        <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='fun.js'></script>
        <title>Panel de usuario</title>  
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id='header'>
            <p class='bienvenida'>Bienvenido ".$usuario."</p>
            <input type='button' class='csesion' value='Cerrar Sesión'>
        </div>

        <div class='contenedor'>
            <img src='imagenes/taller.png'>

            <div class='flex-container'>
                <button class='registrar'>Registrar Vehiculo</button>
                <button class='eliminar'>Eliminar Vehiculo</button>
                <button class='pedircita'>Pedir Cita</button>
                <button class='citas'>Mis Citas</button>
                <button class='tamaño'>Historial de citas</button>
                <button class='añadirtxt'>Pagar Facturas</button>
                <button class='añadir'>Area Personal</button>
            </div>

            <div class='recargar'></div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class='izquierda'>
                <p>Todos los derechos reservados</p>
            </div>
            <div class='derecha'>
                <p><b>Taller Mecánico</b></p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Servicio de automoción</li>
                        <li>C/Tend</li>
                        <li>Mvl. 600300400</li>
                        <li>Tlfn. 985304050</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>";
```

```
<?php
session_start();
require("variables.php");
echo "<link href='estilos/registrarVehiculo.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>";

//Comprobar id de usuario
$query = "select id from usuarios where usuario = '$_SESSION[usuario]'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

    $id_matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
    $marca = $_POST['marca'];
    $modelo = $_POST['modelo'];
    $potencia = $_POST['potencia'];
    $combustible = $_POST['combustible'];
    $año = $_POST['año'];

    $query = "insert into vehiculos (id_matricula, marca, modelo, combustible, potencia, año, usuario) values ('$id_matricula', '$marca', '$modelo', '$combustible', $potencia, $año, '$fila[id]')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    header("Location: user.php");
}
else{

echo "<form action='registrarVehiculo.php' method='POST'>
            <label class='label'>Matrícula</label><br/>
                <input class='input' type='text'  name='matricula' placeholder='0000AAA' maxlength='7' require></br><br/>

            <label class='label'>Marca</label><br/>
                <input class='input' type='text' name='marca' placeholder='Ford' require><br/><br/>

            <label class='label'>Modelo</label><br/>
                <input class='input' type='text' name='modelo' placeholder='Mondeo'require><br/><br/>

            <label class='label'>Potencia</label><br/>
                <input class='input' type='number' name='potencia' placeholder='150' min='40' max='999' size='3'><br/><br/>

            <label class='label'>Año</label><br/>
                <input class='input' type='number' name='año' placeholder='2020' min='1930' max='2021' size='4'><br/><br/>

            <label class='label'>Combustible</label><br/>
                <select name='combustible' class='combustible'>
                    <option value='Diesel'>Diesel</option>
                    <option value='Gasolina'>Gasolina</option>
                    <option value='Electrico'>Eléctrico</option>
                </select><br/><br/>

        <input id='hola' type='submit' name='enviar' value='Registrar Vehiculo'><br/><br/>           
    </form>";
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código? El error lo estás cometiendo al enviar la petición XHR y analizar el resultado, pero no podemos indicarte cómo corregirlo sin ver el código.

Comment: @OscarGarcia publicados!

Comment: Gracias por tu edición @Jorge. He corregido el código PHP para que se vea bien. Por otro lado, el HTML está mal. Comienza y acaba con unas comillas (y al final hay un punto y coma), por lo que asumo que es algo generado en algún sitio, ¿verdad?

Comment: Eso es @OscarGarcia es HTML dentro de mi archivo PHP, y lo que hago al hacer click en el boton, es mostrar ese PHP, y envio al mismo la comprobacion para que m e registre el vehiculo en la base de datos. Funciona, pero al volver al "user.php" a mi panel de usuario, no se como hacer para que me recargue jQuery de nuevo ese PHP, y poder poner por ejemplo en un span "Vehiculo insertado correctamente".

Comment: @OscarGarcia el "problema" que yo puedo ver, es que yo recargo en el div "recargar" el archivo registrarVehiculo.php, este se me muestra corectamente, (es un formulario) y al rellenar los datos y dale a enviar, este va a hacer el insert a la base de datos a el mismo, a registratVehiculo.php y mediante un header(Location: user.php"); lo devuelvo a la pagina del usuario. Lo que sería interesante es que todo ocurriese dentro del div, es decir, que como el input apunta a el mismo, que hiciese la consulta dentro del div, no cambiase de pagina.

Comment: Entoces el formulario deberías enviarlo también por XHR (ahora entiendo por qué no hay datos en la petición, te lo puse en una nota). Esa parte no la has compartido en la pregunta, por eso he entendido otra cosa. ¿Por qué necesitas cargar el formulario por XHR si luego el formulario lo envías normalmente?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Queríaa ahorrar código, y como tengo varios botones, cada vez que haces click, pues en ese div que te recargue solamente ese apartado, para no tener que cargar toda la pagina, pero tendre que hacerlo sin AJAX.. porque ahora mismo no veo la forma que me dices de enviar el formulario con ajax..

Comment: Es que estás usando XHR para hacer el trabajo normal, cuando precisamente se usa para enviar un formulario sin recargar la página (justo lo que no te funciona). Al final no te ahorras código, sólo lo complicas y lo haces más susceptible a fallos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @OscarGarcia voy a probar a ver que consigo!

Answer (score 1):

Estás forzando la actualización del `div` en esta petición XHR:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "registrarVehiculo.php",
    success: function (data) {
        $('.recargar').html(data);
    }
});
```

Tal y como lo tienes programado, haya un error o no reemplazarás el contenido del `<div class="recargar">` por el obtenido del PHP llamado.

Si quieres que se muestre el mensaje sin borrar el formulario deberías crear un `div` nuevo donde mostrar ese cartel de información:

```
<div class='recargar'></div>
<div class='mensaje'></div>
```

Y tu petición XHR modificarla de manera que actualice ese `div`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "registrarVehiculo.php",
    success: function (data) {
        $('.mensaje').html(data);
    },
});
```

Con eso lo que se sobreescribirá será el mensaje recibido por el PHP, y no el formulario que envía el usuario.

PD: No veo por ningún lado cómo mandas el contenido del formulario en esa petición XHR. ¿Es código completo y real?